# Geometric progression of 1 and 1/3tan^2θ

Tags: sequences-and-series

**The first two terms of a geometric progression are [image] where $0<θ<π/2$.

(i) Find the set of values of θ for which the progression is convergent. [2]**

What does convergent mean and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite geometric progression with initial term $1$ and common ratio $r$ can be denoted by:

$$1, r, r^2, r^3,..., r^n, ...$$

For the progression to be convergent, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n$ ("final term") has to be zero, meaning that $|r| < 1$.

So in this case, $r = \frac{1}{3}\tan^2 \theta$. This is always non-negative so you don't really have to worry about the absolute value. All you need to do is solve the inequality:

$$\frac{1}{3}\tan^2 \theta < 1$$

within the given range of values for $\theta$.

Solving,

$$-\sqrt 3 < \tan \theta < \sqrt3$$

Within the required range, that just leaves $0 <\theta < \frac{\pi}{3}$, since the tangent is a strictly increasing function over the relevant domain.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The infinite geometric series  $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ is convergent if and only if $|x|\lt 1$.

**Remark:** As for the *definition* of convergence, let $a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots$ be an infinite series.

For any $n$, let $s_n$ be the partial sum $a_0+a_1+\cdots +a_n$. We say that the series $a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots$ converges if the sequence $(s_n)$ of partial sums has a (finite) limit.

Comment: Thx for the definition but how to get the set of values ??

Comment: Here the "$x$" is $\frac{1}{3}\tan^2\theta$. We don't need to worry about the absolute value business, since $\tan^2\theta$ is never negative. So by the first sentence of my answer, we have convergence precisely if $\frac{1}{3}\tan^2\theta\lt 1$, or equivalently if $\tan^2\theta\lt 3$. Now what angles $\theta$ in the interval $0\lt \theta\lt \pi/2$ have $\tan^2\theta\lt 3$? Think *special angles*.